# Xamarin IOS, reactiveUI 8.7 Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'ReactiveUI,

Tags: xamarin.ios, reactiveui

After upgrade to ReactiveUI 8.7, get the following error when trying to build IOS project.
Anyone know how to solve this?

```
 Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'ReactiveUI, Version=8.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
4>    at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00105] in <cf7a158ef20945e2bfed3d139c691ed5>:0 
4>    at Mono.Linker.AssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/AssemblyResolver.cs:80 
4>    at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.IMetadataScope scope) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/LinkContext.cs:210 
4>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
4>    at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.IMetadataScope scope) [0x00046] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/LinkContext.cs:220 
4>    at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.ResolveReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/LinkContext.cs:254 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/LoadReferencesStep.cs:52 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00049] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/LoadReferencesStep.cs:54 
4>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/LoadReferencesStep.cs:56 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00049] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/LoadReferencesStep.cs:54 
4>  ---
4>  --- inner exception
4>  Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
4>    at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00105] in <cf7a158ef20945e2bfed3d139c691ed5>:0 
4>    at Mono.Linker.AssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/AssemblyResolver.cs:80 
4>    at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.IMetadataScope scope) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/LinkContext.cs:210 
4>    at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.IMetadataScope scope) [0x00046] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/LinkContext.cs:220 
4>    at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.ResolveReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/LinkContext.cs:254 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/LoadReferencesStep.cs:52 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00049] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/LoadReferencesStep.cs:54 
4>  ---
```

Comment: Are you using System.Reactive 4.1.x?

Comment: I am using System.Reactive 4.0.0

Comment: Hmm my iOS application works fine with those versions. Have you tried installing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions explicitly?

Comment: Tried adding nuget manually, and still doesn't work.
`XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, referenced by `System.Reactive`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, or remove the reference to `System.Reactive`.`

Comment: Found solution, downgrade `System.Reactive' to 4.0. You look at the bug issue here.
https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/803